# how to put page number in jsp

Tags: jsp, pagination

i need to put the page no like stackoverflow have at the tags page like 1 2 3 4 5.. next
I am using jsp. Please help me ..

Comment: Please post a code snippet or description of what you have so far.  If this is homework, please mark it with the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pagination](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=pagination+tutorial&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=) is generally pretty easy, but depends almost entirely on how you are getting the data you are paginating.